# How to stay logged in to a website with Python while running a program and requesting data?

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I found a way to stay logged in to a website with Python. The problem is that every once in a while, I get disconnected and logged out. I'm guessing that the session is timing out but I don't know how to fix it.

I used the Live HTTP Headers add-on for Firefox and copied headers from my login request into my program.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

data = urllib.urlencode({"inUserName":"MY EMAIL", "inUserPass":"MY PASSWORD"})
jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Referer', 'http://www.locationary.com/'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','site_version=REGULAR; __utma=47547066.601656247.1344371114.1344602507.1344606239.16; __utmz=47547066.1344371114.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); nickname=jacob501; jforumUserId=1; locaCountry=1227; locaState=null; locaCity=Atlanta; PSESSIONID=533e2fb9fda008d5d16bfbdc9b9a6afed0e5ac54; Locacookie=enable; sortOrder=1; JSESSIONID=DE58AC8BC78D1DF20BF338E195336E58; __utmc=47547066; __utmb=47547066.6.10.1344606239'))
request = urllib2.Request("https://www.locationary.com/index.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=tile_loginBar_jsp$JspView$LoginAction", data)
response = opener.open(request)
page = opener.open(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

I used `cookielib` and `urrlib`/`urllib2`. The cookie that really makes it work is the really long one, But I don't really know what it all means and I just copied it in from the add-on. If my connection goes out, I go to my browser and log in again and get a new cookie from the add-on. Like I said before, I'm guessing it has to do with the session or the sessionid or something, but I don't know how I can make it so that I am always logged in.

Thanks.

#### EDIT

Can someone tell me why this is a bad question or am I just stupid? -1 for what?

#### EDIT 2

Okay! If I don't **stay** logged in, then is there a way to keep my connection/cookie from not working?

#### EDIT 3

I don't know how to **get a new cookie** other than going to the Firefox add-on myself...haha

#### EDIT 4

Okay. I made a new test program:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import re

url = 'http://www.locationary.com/home/index2.jsp'

data = urllib.urlencode({"inUserName":"email", "inUserPass":"password"})
jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Referer', 'http://www.locationary.com/'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','site_version=REGULAR; __utma=47547066.601656247.1344371114.1344612897.1344615635.18; __utmz=47547066.1344371114.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); nickname=jacob501; jforumUserId=1; locaCountry=1227; locaState=null; locaCity=Atlanta; PSESSIONID=533e2fb9fda008d5d16bfbdc9b9a6afed0e5ac54; Locacookie=enable; sortOrder=1; JSESSIONID=781FD0C497FB596954BB78B1323215F6; __utmc=47547066; __utmb=47547066.9.10.1344615635'))
request = urllib2.Request("https://www.locationary.com/index.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=tile_loginBar_jsp$JspView$LoginAction", data)
response = opener.open(request)
page = opener.open(url).read()
print re.findall(r'<title>(.*)</title>', page)
h = response.info().headers
print h
```

Output:

```
['Home Page']
['Server: nginx/1.0.8\r\n', 'Date: Fri, 10 Aug 2012 16:50:47 GMT\r\n', 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n', 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n', 'Connection: close\r\n', 'P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"\r\n']
```

Comment: there is nothing like "stayed logged in". HTTP is stateless.

Comment: @Maulwurfn: considering he's using cookies, I think you can understand what he means.

Comment: I know one session implementation (seaside) and there is no way to get around the session timeout because it is implemented on the server side. Can't you get a new Cookie after 10 minutes?

Comment: if you requst with an invalid cookie, what happens?

Comment: does firefox log you out? after some time?

Comment: If I don't use the website, then usually Firefox logs me out. It seems that the same thing happens when I put it in my program...the URLs and HTML pages I request come back as the home page.

Comment: But it takes a while (kinda long time) to log me out...I was just getting tired of going and getting new cookies

Comment: It sounds like the server is clearing the session after a certain amount of time, making your cookie invalid.  The only way to work around that is to simulate the whole request/response cycle of logging back in through your python script.

Comment: the server sends a new cookie every time you request - also to your python program. Maybe you extract that Cookie and request with this new cookie before the session times out. (skip this if firefox receives the same cookie every time)

Comment: @Joe Day How do I "simulate the whole request/response cycle"? The only thing I know how to do is send a request with the cookie firefox gave me...

Comment: @user1320237 I think I could do that but how do I get the cookie that it gives to my python program?? I think the cookie does change.

Comment: @MarcusJohnson You would go to the site, find the login form, look to see what fields it submits to the server and what url it submits them to, then simulate an equivalent http request from your python script, then read the response headers to grab the new value for your authentication cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using the [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) module and seeing if that makes a difference?

Take a look at the examples [here](http://pydanny.blogspot.com/2011/05/python-http-requests-for-humans.html); it's very easy to use, and the built-in cookie jar may help if only to prevent you from accidentally making mistakes in Python's otherwise miserable HTTP libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium, to use firefox to stay logged in into this webpage.
[selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html)

```
from selenium import selenium

localport = 12345

## you create a socket proxy here listening on localport
## connecting to www.locationary.com:80

selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, 
                    "*firefox", "http://localhost:%i" % localport)

while 1:
    # open the selenium side every 5 minutes
    selenium.open("/home/index2.jsp")
    selenium.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
    time.sleep(5 * 60) # seconds
```

to install selenium you need the python package and the selenium server .jar file to start it.

Because firefox logs in through you program, you can parse the traffic for valid session ids.

Questions?